# What happend to SMART data (disk selftest option)

Tags: boot, hard-drive, gnome-disk-utility

My question is; What happened to SMART data selftest option in Disks/gnome-disk-utility

Any help or tips appreciated.(I want to scan/repair my drive for bad sectors preferably GUI)

here is an image of what I am looking for:
[image]

I was told this is a duplicate question. However I was totally lost looking for the "gear icon" This is how mine looks in Kubuntu [image]

It might sound silly but I did not make the connection with that "hamburger" being the "gear icon"

Comment: It's still there. Click that pestilential hamburger button in the top right corner of the Disks window and you'll find a "SMART values and self-test" or similar menu point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select `Dash` the first option on the `Launcher` and type `disks`. Select the icon that appears.

The `disks` main screen looks like this:

[image: disks main]

Notice the "hamburger" menu in the top right corner. Select it to get a drop down menu where you can select the SMART screen shown below:

[image: disks SMART]

If you require further explanation please comment below.

Comment: thank you... I don't get how I missed that all this time :-)

Comment: You're welcome. I'm sure I've missed more than you :)

Comment: some guys marked this as a duplicate. I disagree. But feel stupid about it :-)

Comment: I see your disagreement. The question and answers were written for Ubuntu 14.04. As the software was upgraded they changed the question to say "Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.10" which is misleading because no one changed the answers that are for 14.04". The question should have stayed the same and new answers should have been added instead.

Comment: @MarcoSchoolenberg I raised the issue with a mod who understands integrity within Q&A better than myself and can hopefully fix things up so it doesn't happen again.